# iTunesConnect always keeping app in "pre release"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have uploaded new build(version 1.0.2) and they rejected (meta data rejection) because i didnt give test login details. After i added test login and updated then they again rejected.

Then i made some changes and uploaded a new version(version 1.0.3) itself but that version went into "Pre Release"  and i tried to upload more versions  like 1.0.4 etc.. but i can see every version still in pre release . Its almost 3-4 days. So just now i have uploaded one more version 1.0.6 (validation and everything was successful) now i can see 1.0.6 again come under pre release. Please help me.

```
If i uploaded same binary 1.0.2 then it will go to "waiting for review " state and after 5-10 minutes it showing invalid binary and rejected in red color.
```

Please help me... here is itunes connect screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you need to check the reason of the rejections, that would help you to solve the issue.

Comment: bcoz i didnt add meta data

Comment: now iam uploading like version 1.0.2 and bundle 1.0.2.1 lets see it its work or not.uploading in progress

Comment: Would it help if you turn on TestFlight Beta Testing, the switch in your screen shot. You won't be abel to release a beta until you turn that on. If you want to release it, you need to create a new version in iTC with eh version number you uploaded, and then add the build.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I realized my app does not support 64 bit.  After Feb 1st, all new apps submitted must include 64 bit support.  From looking at your upload dates, it looks like you may have come across this issue.  In build settings under 'Architectures' make sure 'Standard Architectures' is set.

Comment: this is how my architecture looks like ...i have uploaded screenshot of xcode  http://postimg.org/gallery/33lcexdxu/

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way of application submission apple introduced.

If you upload any new build it will go to prerelease section. Here you can add your internal testers to test this Pre-Release build..If not approved by your tester then you can add another build with same version and updated build number.This cycle can repeat..

At last if your tester approved particular build then you can go to new version in iTC and in build section if you click + button you can see all these testing build.Then you can select any of the build(probably QA approved build) to apple review.

FYI : This PreRelease is introduced after Apple acquired "TestFlight"